# How to access a data attribute via the .on method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

This is my attempt to get the HTML data attribute named `productId`:

```
$('body').on("click", '.myButton', function () {
    var productId = (this).dataset.productId;
});
```

I have several buttons with the class `myButton`, each with different productIds as their data.

But in this case, the code just look for the *data from the body tag* and not from the buttons with the class `myButton`.

How can I specify the DOM element I want to extract the data?

Ideally this should work for me in the first place, but for some reason it isn't:

```
 $('.myButton').on("click", null, function () {
        var productId = (this).dataset.productId;
 });
```

Comment: Add `$` before `(this)`

Comment: If you search, there has to be thousands of questions and answers on here that show you how to get data attributes with `data()` or `attr()`, why would you use `dataset` ?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML of the button?

Comment: "_But in this case, the code just look for the data from the body tag and not from the buttons with the class myButton._", That't not true, `this` refers to the clicked element.

Comment: @undefined You're right. Thanks. And now this works using attr as the posted answer stated.

Comment: @Arman The issue should be related to `dataset`, older browsers do not support this property.

Comment: @undefined So my firefox is outdated... Better not use dataset anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery up to and including version 1.4, data attributes were case insensitive, therefore:

```
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="click me" data-productId="abc"/>
```

would be accessible with

```
$('.myButton').data('productId');​
```

**jQuery 1.5 and 1.6**

However, changes in jQuery 1.5 and 1.6 mean that data attributes are now forced to lowercase, so:

```
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="click me" data-productId="abc"/>
```

is only accessible with

```
$('.myButton').data('productid');​
```

Although there is a bug in [`jQuery 1.5 and later`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8474) that prevents us from upgrading the version of jQuery.

Therefore, you should avoid using camel-cased data attributes in your HTML, and stick to all lowercase attributes such as

```
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="click me" data-productid="abc"/>
```

or use dashed attributes such as

```
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="click me" data-product-id="abc"/>
```

and then expect to deal with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) items of 'productid'.

Try this:

```
$('body').on("click", '.myButton', function() {
    var productId = $(this).attr('data-productId');
    alert(productId);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sf27U/)**

Comment: This works. But how come .attr do while neither .data nor dataset worked?

Answer (score 0):

maybe somethig like this ?

```
  $('body').on("click", '.myButton', function () {
       var productId = $(this).data("productId");
  });
```